# Multiple regression - low F-statistics and multiple R-squared. What should i do/conclude

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, multiple-regression

I have two independent variable and one dependent variable. This is my summary when I use `lm(y~x_1+x_2)`:

```
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-22.265  -9.563  -1.916   6.405  39.319 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  23.0107    18.2849   1.258  0.21407   
x_1          23.6386     6.8479   3.452  0.00114 **
x_2          -0.7147     0.3014  -2.371  0.02163 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 14.84 on 50 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2018,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1699 
F-statistic: 6.321 on 2 and 50 DF,  p-value: 0.00357
```

I got stuck because neither the F value and R squared are very significant. However the p-value is less than 0.05. Does it mean that y depends on both variables? What should I do next in my regression analysis?

Comment: Your F value is significant. R squared is a descriptive statistic; it cannot be significant or not.

Comment: R square of 0.20 would be considered very large in many applications outside of STEM.

Comment: In addition to comment by @gung; I would suggest not to relay on just mathematical values. Carefully examine scatter-plot matrix & regression diagnostic plots to understand how your variables are residuals behave. Do post estimation analysis and improve your model accordingly. Also consider if there is any interaction effect present. "What should I do next in my regression analysis?" can't be answer exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R^2$ is conventionally interpreted as the percentage of variation in the $y$-term captured or "accounted for" by the regression model. As pointed out in the comments, that value of 0.20 might be considered pretty favorable in some applications. I remember the example dataset we were given in our linear regression course where we modeled hospital cost data and getting to an $R^2$ of 0.15 was the best we could achieve.

The penultimate question would require that you remove one and then the other variable and examine the coefficients. You probably need to look at their joint distribution, possibly with graphical methods.

The value of the $F$-statistic in measuring the amount of variation captured by the regression versus the amount that remains in the unexplained variation in the residuals. It's highly significant, although the $R^2$ does suggest that further analysis would still have the potential to explain some of the rest of the variability. Got any other variables in that dataset? Modeling often proceeds by building on initial models and yours looks promising. Do you have any existing science or theory to guide the model construction process?

Depending on what `y`, `x_1` and `x_2` "in reality" are measuring, you might want to do some residual plots to see in there is a systematic departure from the expect Gaussian distribution of residuals around 0 across the range of `x_1` and `x_2` values respectively. Spline fits or polynomial fits may be considered if there are no other variables available to investigate.

Comment: I only have $y$, $x_1$, $x_2$ as variables.
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x_1 + x_2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          x_1          x_2  
    23.0107      23.6386      -0.7147 

 
This is the coefficient of the variables.
What do you mean by their joint distribution?? Sorry I am very bad at this.

Comment: To make any comments about this particular dataset, one would typically start by examining the variance and covariance of the predictors and dependent variable. Plots of residual|x1, resduals|x2; Y|x_1; Y|x_2 and x_1|x_2 would be useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. I did some more work on it and I noticed that the P value for intercept is a bit high. So I dropped the intercept and my F-statistics, p-value and R square look more promising. However, when I did the residual plot for both  lm(y~x_1+x_2) and lm(y~x_1+x_2-1), neither of them indicated it is a normal linear model. I tried log(y), too. It did not help either. Do you have anymore advice?? Thanks so much again!!

Comment: Unless you know why you should almost never "drop the intercept" then you should not do it. You should say what you mean by "neither ... is a normal linear model". The P-value of the intercept is really only an indication for whether the mean of Y values are near zero. It is NOT a signal that suggests dropping the intercept. I think we now have sufficient evidence to say that you really need to seek the advice of a real statistician who can work with you on this data.